# When downloaded from GooglePlay my app gives javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Tags: java, android, encryption

I made signed release APK of my app and copied it to my phone via USB and installed it.It Works fine. And then I uploaded the SAME APK file to GooglePlay and installed it from there. But when I open the app, it stays on SplashScreen.
I used LogCat to detect the error and here is the log:

> 10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
>   10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_CipherFinal_ex(Native Method)
>   10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.doFinalInternal(OpenSSLCipher.java:430)
>   10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:466)
>   10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1340)
>   10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err:     at com.maptriks.nevo.helper.SecurityHelper.decrypt(SecurityHelper.java:101)
>   10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err:     at com.maptriks.nevo.helper.SecurityHelper.decrypt(SecurityHelper.java:91)
>   10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err:     at com.maptriks.nevo.manager.api.BodyRequest.parseNetworkResponse(BodyRequest.java:76)
>   10-04 13:37:22.052 29875-29903/? W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:123)

I googled the BadPaddingException but all the questions were related to encrypting/decrypting KEYs that apps use. However in my situation it works fine BEFORE uploading it to GooglePlay which I think eliminates the encrypting/decrypting error parts.

First, I thought that ProGuard was doing something, and then I disabled it in gradle. And still I have the same problem.

*Update:*
I checked apk fingerprints, my apps SHA1 fingerprint is not the same with the apk's that is downloaded from GooglePlay. Can it be the cause of the error?
My app works perfectly until I upload it into the GoolePlay.

Answer (score 0):

You should add some extra logs to `com.maptriks.nevo.manager.api.BodyRequest.parseNetworkResponse(BodyRequest.java:76)` and to `com.maptriks.nevo.helper.SecurityHelper.decrypt(SecurityHelper.java:101)`  to check, what happening.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.